Add members to Distribution list using python
I am working on application which uses Graph api to add members in Azure AD groups. And I found that Graph API cannot be  used to add members to Distribution list. I have tried using exhangelib package to access the DL but it keeps freezing on the
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=email, config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)
Is there any way to modify the DL? the Exchange server is hosted Cloud.

EWS doesn't allow you to add members to an Azure Ad Distribution list it only allows you to do CRUD operation on personal Distribution lists that are located in a users contacts folder. Exov3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/whats-new-in-the-exo-module?view=exchange-ps can be used to modify Azure DL's
